# Passing multiple parameters on javascript, using a php variable

Tags: php, javascript, variables, parameters

I have the following javascript, which reloads a php site into a div:

```
if (boxes.length) {
          $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
            // Change the name here as well
            $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
            function() {
                $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
                $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
            });
```

I would like to pass another parameter in the same url...

So I thought I should just do it as follows, although I cannot get it to work. Is this the right way?

I am trying to pass parameter `categ` using a php variable `$category` like this:

```
 if (boxes.length) {
        $(".loadingItems").fadeIn(300);
        // Change the name here as well
        $(".indexMain").load('indexMain.php?categ=<?php echo $category;?>&'+this.name+'=' + boxes.join("+"),
        function() {
            $(".indexMain").fadeIn('slow');
            $(".loadingItems").fadeOut(300);
        });
```

Comment: Looks ok. Can you show the rendered output please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 potential reasons for this not to work (the code seems fine...):

1. The php does not get executed; the javascript is located in an external `.js` file or the html file has for example the `.html` extension instead of `.php`;
2. The variable you echo, contains invalid characters. You should use [`urlencode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) to make sure that does not happen: `<?php echo urlencode($category); ?>`